# ¿ Como funciona la herencia en C++ ? ( aka 'invalid initialization of reference of type 'const Hija&' from expression of type 'const Base' )

Tags: c++, poo, herencia

Vengo del mundo python y me está costando trabajo entender como funciona la herencia en C++.

Entiendo que todas las cosas han de tener un tipo, y que este es fijo e inmutable durante todo su *tiempo-de-vida*. Sin embargo, no entiendo porqué en algunas situaciones me deja hacer conversiones de tipos y en otras no. Mas concretamente, es posible convertir de unas clases en otras **solo a veces**.

Por ejemplo:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct Token { };

struct Function : public Token { };

struct Test {
    std::map< string, Token > tokens;
    std::map< string, Function > functions;

    template< typename T > const T &getItem( const std::string &name ) const {
        auto tokenIter = tokens.find( name );
        if( tokenIter == tokens.end( ) ) {
            return ( functions.find( name ) )->second;
        }

        return tokenIter->second;
    }
};

int main( ) {
    Test test;

    auto &token = test.getItem< Token >( "hola" ); // <- Esto funciona sin problemas.
    auto &funct = test.getItem< Function >( "hola" ); // <- Esto NO FUNCIONA.

    return 0;
}
```

Ese código me genera el *bonito* error

> error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'const Function&' from expression of type 'const Token' ( `return tokenIter->second;` )

En la línea

`auto &funct = test.getItem< Function >( "hola" );`

- ¿ En que consiste este error y como lo soluciono ?

Comment: No sé cómo es en python, pero en C# y Java necesitas castear una variable para usarla en una variable de menor jerarquía. En C++ debes hacer lo mismo. Por lo que el problema se soluciona escribiendo `return (T)tokenIter->second`

Comment: Cierto, podrías hacer un `reinterpret_cast` para forzar al compilador ... pero te estarías engañando a ti mismo. Tendrías una referencia a una clase base, por mucho que forzaras a clase hija. Tendrías variables-miembro internas con valores totalmente erráticos.

Comment: No me refiero a eso. De hecho, si pasas el código por https://cppinsights.io verás que lo reemplaza por un `static_cast`

Comment: Me parece que no has entendido el problema: devolver una clase base como referencia a una clase hija, y no al reves (esto último, como dices, es trivial).

Answer (score 9):

## Python

Primero, un breve resumen de como funciona la herencia en python (aunque es similar en muchos otros lenguajes, por ejemplo JavaScript).

En python, un objeto no es mas que **un diccionario**. Y la herencia no es mas que una *ruta-de-búsqueda* basada en diccionarios:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

1. La clase `Object` tiene ciertos valores ya establecidos.
2. Nuestra clase `MyClass1` asigna un valor a la clave `__str__` y añade al diccionario las claves `__init__` y `myfunct`.
3. Nuestra clase `MyClass2( MyClass )` tienes sus propias claves `__init__` y `myfunct2`.

Ahora, si tu haces

```
instance = MyClass2( )
```

Python busca en el diccionario que es tu clase `MyClass2` la clave `__init__( )`. Si no la encuentra, seguiría la cadena y la buscaría en el diccionario que es tu clase `MyClass1`, si tampoco lo encuentra buscaría en el diccionario que es la clase `Object`, y, si tampoco lo encuentra ahí, lanzaría una excepción.

<sub>**Nota**: Esto es una simplificación con intención académica para tener un punto de partida, no una explicación detallada.</sub>

## C++

En C++, la herencia funciona de forma totalmente diferente. Y tenemos que hacer una pequeña introducción aclaratoria.

### ¿ Que es una `class` / `struct` en C++ ?

Una `class`/`struct` no es mas que una sucesión de elementos en memoria. Por ejemplo, esta definición:

```
struct Estudiante {
    char nombre[50];
    int edad;
    int altura;
};
```

Generaría en memoria algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Después de esta pequeña introducción, ya llegamos a lo que nos interesa:

### Herencia en C++

El punto clave aquí es que la herencia **es aditiva**.

Si ahora definimos una nueva clase:

```
struct EstudianteAvanzado : public Estudiante {
    int matriculasDeHonor;
};
```

En memoria se generaría algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se aprecia claramente que un `EstudianteAvanzado` **es un** `Estudiante`. Tiene los mismo campos y en las mismas posiciones ... mas un campo añadido, `matriculasDeHonor`, que está a continuación de los campos heredados de `Estudiante`.

<sub>**Nota**: Esto es una breve explicación en un *mundo-ideal*. No se hace referencia a métodos virtuales ni herencia virtual, puesto que extenderían muy mucho la respuesta.</sub>

### El Problema

Tomando el error de la pregunta:

> error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'const Function&' from expression of type 'const Token`

Ya podemos verlo con claridad.

Siempre que tengamos un `EstudianteAvanzado` podemos tratarlo **exactamente igual** que si fuera un *simple* `Estudiante`, puesto que contiene todos los atributos esperados, y en las mismas posiciones relativas de memoria. Como dije antes, un `EstudianteAvanzado` **es un** `Estudiante`.

**Pero** ... al revés **no es posible**. No podemos tratar un `Estudiante` como si fuera un `EstudianteAvanzado`: ¿ Que pasa si intentamos acceder a `matriculasDeHonor` de un `Estudiante` ? Esa `struct` **no tiene** ese campo. Si accedemos a la posición de memoria en la que se supone que va a estar, encontraríamos *basura* aleatoria. No sería un valor correcto.

Y eso es justamente lo que te está diciendo el error:

> No puedes tratar una expresión de tipo `Estudiante` como si fuera del tipo `EstudianteAvanzado`.

Y el compilador, con toda su *buena fe*, te lo está indicando.